# jquery .find/.closest/.next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with one row having 4 cells as below

```
<table class="Header3" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td id="RC" class="contLabel" style="width: 228px">
            <div class="abc">Related Companies</div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 101px">
            <asp:checkbox runat="server" id="RCR" type="checkbox" ENABLED="false"/>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 116px">
            <asp:checkbox runat="server" id="RCP" type="checkbox" ENABLED="false"/>
        </td>
        <td id="RC2" class="contLabel">Are related companies used to improve results?</td>
    </tr>
```

And I below the table, i have a textbox inside div, the code is below:

```
<div id="RCN" class="panel2" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="ContentTB">
        <asp:TextBox  id="RCNT" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" width="99.5%" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is the moment I click the first cell (#RC) or the 4th cell (#RC2), the textbox below the table get toggled, currently my jquery code is

```
$(function() {
    $('#RC,#RC2').click(function(e) {
        $('#RCN').toggle('fast');
    });
})
```

and it works ok.

Now problem is that I have 20 tables and 20 textboxe, and I don't want to write 20 lines jquery code.
I'm trying things like

```
$('.contLabel').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next('.panel2').toggle('fast');
});
```

but it does not work. I wonder what's the correct code?

The reason that I don't put all of them in one table is that the toggle animation does not look good.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Format and indent your code properly, and try to explain the exact relationship between the elements, as there has to be one to target the right textbox ?

Comment: You should probably use `$(this)` instead of `$('this')`.

Comment: thank you, I fixed that to this. Though the problem still occurs

Comment: Querying for `'panel2'` searches for an element whose tag name is `'panel2'`. To search for a class, use `.panel2`.

Comment: sorry about my typos, I changed it to class, the problem still occurs

Comment: So now that we’ve got the typos out of the way: `next` is probably the wrong jQuery function to use as it only searches the element immediately proceeding the context. As there is either nothing after a `.contLabel` or only a `div` with class `abc`, your selector `'.panel2'` will never match and will return an empty set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to go back up to the `table` using `closest()` then use `next()` to get the div with the textarea in it.

```
$('.contLabel').on('click', function (e) {
  var $td = $(this);
  $td.closest('table').next('.panel2').toggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: sorry, what does textarea mean?

Comment: Whatever that asp:textbox thing puts out.

Comment: I think he is trying to toggle the div:'.panel2' and not the textarea.

Comment: Understood. Updated it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
$('.contLabel').click(function (e) {
  $(this).parent('tr').parent('tbody').parent('table').next('.panel2').toggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: The parent of `$(this)` would be the `<tr>`. I did not down vote that upvote, though!

Comment: Sorry, i tried the code. For some reason it doesn't work. but the post above this one works well.

Comment: Actually, the parent of the `<tr>` might even be a `<tbody>`, depending on whether the document is true XHTML or not. So the answer with `closest` is way more elegant.